# How to get count of data using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table data and user. I need to get count of data->value and show only greatest count and user->name.

eg, user_id 2: count is 3

I tried some query but it's wrong.

```
SELECT data.value, user.name 
FROM data 
INNER JOIN user 
ON data.value = user.id 
WHERE data.field = 'user_id'
```

**DATA**

```
id  order_id   field     value (id of user table)
1      1      user_id     1  
2      2      user_id     3
3      3      user_id     2
4      4      user_id     2
5      5      user_id     1
6      6      user_id     2
```

**USER**

```
id    name  
 1    foo
 2    joo
 3    peter
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to filter data with user_id?

Comment: @Sadikhasan Expected result is user_id 2 has three entry in data table. So result would be user_id 2 has 3 count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Data is dependent on user's records and each user has multile associated rows in the data table, we need to use **GROUP BY**.
- We need to find the user with the maximum count. For that, the count column is arranged in descending order using **ORDER BY** count DESC  and the very first row with the max. value is extracted using **LIMIT 0, 1**.

Try this:

```
SELECT data.value, user.name, data.field, COUNT(*) as count
FROM data 
INNER JOIN user 
ON data.value = user.id 
GROUP BY user.name
HAVING data.field = 'user_id'
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Output:

```
value  |  name  |  field  |  count
  2    |  john  | user_id |    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use group by

```
select count(value) from tablename group by value;
```

this will give you count 3 according to your table

Answer (score -1):

According to your example requirement, you can do something like this :-

```
SELECT data.value AS user_id, 
data.field, 
COUNT( * ) AS count 
FROM data 
INNER JOIN user 
ON data.value = user.id 
GROUP BY user.name 
HAVING data.field = 'user_id' 
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Comment: Please offer some consoling commentary like OM did to further explain your answers Manish. And format your output so we don't have to.